# PHP SQL query to populate nested menu?

Tags: php, jquery, sql

I'm building a website that uses a tab menu for months of the year and then an accordion menu within each month/tab to list all events that took place in that month.

I'm new to using PHP when populating websites and I'm having some trouble in getting the code to work. The pre-PHP code would look something like this:

```
<div class="tabscontainer">
<div class="tabs">
    <div class="tab selected first" id="tab_menu_1">
        <div class="link">$Month</div>
        <div class="arrow"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<div class="curvedContainer">
<div class="tabcontent" id="tab_content_1" style="display:block">
    <div id="page">     
    <ul id="example4" class="accordion">
        <li>
        <h3>$EventListGoesHere</h3>
            <div class="panel loading">
                <p>Some content here.</p>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've tried using the while loop but I keep breaking my code. The while loop I'm trying to use is:

```
<?php 
// Connects to your Database 
mysql_connect("iphere", "username", "password") or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db("dbname") or die(mysql_error()); 
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM MonthTable") 
or die(mysql_error()); 
while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
{ 
Print "My code here"; 
Nested SQL code to got through events table here.   
} 
?>
```

I guess my question is, am I going down the right road and, if so, could somebody give me an idea of how the standard code should fit within the PHP while loop?

My DB is something like:

MonthTable
ID  | MonthShort |  MonthLong
1 | 2012Oct | October 2012
2 | 2012Sep | September 2012

EventTable
ID | MonthID | Event
1 | 1 | Wedding
2 | 1 | Bar Mitzvah
3 | 1 | Funeral
4 | 2 | Birthday
5 | 2 | Birthday
6 | 2 | Wedding

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do just one query. For example:

```
<?php

$sql = "
  SELECT
    a.id, b.id AS monthId, a.event, b.monthshort, b.monthlong
  FROM
    events_table_name AS a
  INNER JOIN
    month_table_name AS b ON b.id = a.monthId
  ORDER BY
    b.id, a.id ASC
  ";

// rest of db stuff here

$events = array();
$months = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  if (! isset($events[$row["monthId"]])) {
    $events[$row["monthId"]] = array();
  }
  $months[$row["monthId"]] = $row["monthlong"];
  $events[$row["monthId"]][] = $row["event"];
}

for ($x = 1; $x <= 12; $x++) {
  echo '<div class="tab" id="tab_$x">';
  if (isset($events[$x])) {
    echo '<div class="month-title">' . $months[$x] . '</div>';
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ($events[$x] as $event) {
      echo "<li>". $event ."</li>";
    }
    echo '</ul>';
  }
  echo '</div>';
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

What errors are you getting? That while loop is fine. Look into using mysqli. A standard mysqli loop would be:

```
$db=new mysqli('host','user','pass');
$q=$db->query("SELECT * FROM db.table");
while ($f=$q->fetch_assoc()) {
     print_r($f);
     // echo "<br>"; 
}
```

Try that and it will show you the array you get for each row of the loop. Again, what errors are you getting?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear . I'd messed up on the nested element but I've now fixed it. Thanks for your reply!